# How do I change the volume of the OutputDevice in the DryWetMIDI library?

Tags: c#, midi

I am writing a MidiEditor in C# where I work with MIDI data and MIDI devices using the DryWetMIDI library.

I found in the documentation that the `OutputDevice` class has a `GetProperty(OutputDeviceProperty)` method in which you can pass enum `OutputDeviceOption.Volume`, to get the output device volume value. But in my case unfortunately it returns just text "Volume" instead of value.

Please provide me with an example of how to get the OutputDevice volume value correctly and how to change it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi).

First of all, `OutputDeviceOption.Volume` just means that a device supports volume control. This option is not for getting volume. And that for Windows only. Right now there is no way to get/set volume of an output device.

DryWetMIDI Devices API supports Windows and macOS. There are functions to control volume in Windows but such API missing in macOS so it's impossible to provide universal API. Also I had problems with setting volume of output devices when I played with Windows API. So I've decided to not provide volume management methods at all.